# Using if else on columns in server side jquery data table with ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, datatable, conditional-statements

Its been a while since I am looking for the answer.
Problem is I used ajax request to populate my datatable always and could easily apply if else condition based on the column values, but this practice is good for data less than 50,000. Today I happen to use datatable on a bigger dataset having more rows, so I used this code:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
    columns: [
        {'data': 'employer_id' },
        { 'data': 'intern_id' } 
    ],

    sAjaxSource: '../EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployees',
    sServerMethod: 'post' 
    })
});
```

Used web service to fetch data and a stored procedure for the server side processing which works like a charm. Now, my question is, how to use if else on this table like for example, if I have "abc" in column1, I want to Display "ABC" in datatable.
HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       columnDefs: [ {
                 targets: 0,
                 render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                     if (data == 0) {
                         return "zero";
                     }
                     else
                         return "non zero";
                 }
             },
             {
                 targets: 1,
                 render: function (data, type, row) {
                     if (data == 0) {
                         return " intern zero";
                     }
                     else
                         return "intern non zero";
                 }
             }]
```

This has done the job.